# Connect to URL and dump webpage in Groovy

Tags: url, groovy, html, dump

I would like to open a webpage from groovy, dump the specified webpage and eventually dump the webpage behind an  anchor tag.

Does anybody has some sample code for this?

Answer (score 62, accepted):

This is a good example

http://docs.codehaus.org/display/GROOVY/Simple+file+download+from+URL

Basically you want to do something like

```
def data = new URL(feedUrl).getText()
```

Answer (score 91):

here is a variation

```
println 'http://www.google.com'.toURL().text
```

Comment: as for me any getter method which actually can have params is handier to call directly. getText('utf-8') cannot be shortcuted.

Comment: this getter doesn't have params

Comment: Love this. When I code in Groovy, I feel guilty since complicated tasks are so simple!