# How to trigger several downstream builds in groovy and then finish the upstream job without waiting for results

Tags: groovy, jenkins

I would like to trigger several downstream builds in groovy and then make the upstream job finish without waiting for the results of the downstream jobs.

With the following code:

```
hudson.model.queue.QueueTaskFuture build(String fullName) { 
 def p = jenkins.model.Jenkins.instance.getItemByFullName(fullName) 
 def thisR = Thread.currentThread().executable 
 def f = p.scheduleBuild2(p.quietPeriod, new hudson.model.Cause.UpstreamCause(thisR)) 
 return f 
} 

def f1 = build('job1') 
def f2 = build('job2') 

// wait for both builds to finish 
def b1 = f1.get() 
def b2 = f2.get()
```

The downstream builds must finish before the upstream job can finish.  Can I force the upstream job to finish with a build status of SUCCESS while the downstream jobs continue to run?

Comment: Sorry, but I can't understand a problem. You can just comment last two lines and your upstream build will not be blocked by downstream builds.

Answer (score 0):

I think you could call the URL to start the job using the [remote access API](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Remote+access+API)

> You merely need to perform an HTTP POST on
>   ﻿JENKINS_URL/job/JOBNAME/build?token=TOKEN where TOKEN is set up in
>   the job configuration.

Which can be done in [groovy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/943873/connect-to-url-and-dump-webpage-in-groovy)

```
def data = new URL(feedUrl).getText()
```