# How to download and output html page using grails?

Tags: grails, get

I have to download HTML code of the external site page and output received data.

I wanna use it like (in my controller):

```
def download() {
    // get and output page code
}
```

but i have bo idea how to do that.

Comment: This question has been asked many times before. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/943873/connect-to-url-and-dump-webpage-in-groovy

Comment: Maybe does he want to know how to set the response head and send file bytes to the browser?